# Is it possible to copy a flash ad displayed on Skype window?

Tags: reverse-engineer

I need a create a design similar to a flash ad feastured in a Skype window. Can I copy it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - use a sniffer to find the URL from which the ad is loaded. It would most probably be a .swf or .flv file. You can then download it (using your browser, or FTP program) and dissect it in your own free time - there are tons of flash tools out there to help you.